# Borel sigma algebra is the same as the sigma algebra generated by open rational-ends intervals.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Consider $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the following collection of open intervals:
$$F=\{(a,b) : a,b\in \Bbb{Q}, a<b \}$$

For every $A \subset \Bbb{R}$ we denote $\sigma (A)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$.
I have to prove that $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})=\sigma(F)$.

For the left-to-right inclusion, let $U$ be an open set in the usual topology. By the definition of this topology:

$$\exists \{a_i,b_i\}_{i\in I} \subset \Bbb{R}, a_i < b_i : U = \cup_{i\in I} (a_i,b_i)$$

By the construction of real numbers,  $$\forall i \in I \, \exists \{q_n^i,r_n^i\}_{n\in \Bbb{N}} \subset \Bbb{Q}: a_i=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} q_n^i ,b_i=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} r_n^i$$ where $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}: a<q_{n+1}^i < q_n^i, r_n^i < r_{n+1}^i <b$. Let denote $n_0 := \min \{k\in \Bbb{N}:q_k^i < r_k^i \} $. Then, since $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions:
$$\forall i \in I : (a_i,b_i) = \cup_{n \geq n_0} (q_n^i,r_n^i) \in \sigma(F) \Rightarrow U \in \sigma(F) $$
Since Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by open subsets, we have $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}) \subset \sigma(F)$.

For the right-to-left inclusion, any interval in $F$ is an open interval, so $F\subset \mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$.

I want to know if I am right with this prove, any comments or corrections would be appreciated.